# How to get my [shortcode] rendered on the home page, other pages are fine

Tags: php, theme-development, shortcode

I'm using a child theme of [Pixlex](http://www.themes4all.com/themes/pixlex/).

The theme has a options panel to let me choose wether I want 2 or 3 columns on the home page and if those columns are to be filled with a post or page.

I have one of the columns is set to be filled with a page that has been created and that page has a shortcode for a button placed in it. (the shortcode is provided by the themes code itself)

My problem is that when the home page is rendered the column that pulls in the page shows the shortcode as not being parsed and I am left with:
`[bigbutton url="http://somelink.com" color="yellow"]The Button[/bigbutton]`

I was hoping someone here might see something that I am not.

Here is the code in the homepage template that is pulling in the 3rd column.

```
<?php  

if($options['basic_homebox3'] && $options['basic_homebox3']!=2){ 

$args = array('page_id' =>$options['basic_homebox3'], );
$post_h = get_post($options['basic_homebox3']);
$title = $post_h->post_title;
$sjc_excerpt = explode( '<!--more-->', $post_h->post_content); 
$permalink = get_permalink( $options['basic_homebox3'] );
$i=1;
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>   
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
      if($i<2){
      ?>
        <div class="span4">
                <div class="home-threebox lastbox">
                    <h2 class="homepage-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                    <div class="homepage-excerpt">
                      <?php echo wpautop( $sjc_excerpt[0] ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div> 
        </div>        
        <?php 
          }
         $i++;
         endwhile; ?>
         <?php 
         endif;
         }else{
         ?>
            <div class="span4">
                <div class="home-threebox lastbox">
                    <h2 class="homepage-title">Third box</h2>
                    <div class="homepage-excerpt">
                      <p>Suspendisse nisl.</p>
                    </div>
                <div>
            </div>       
<?php
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the filter I was looking for:

```
apply_filters('the_content',$content);
```

A simple fix I replaced this code:

`<?php echo wpautop( $sjc_excerpt[0] ); ?>`

with this

`<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$sjc_excerpt[0]); ?>`

Now the shortcode is rendered!

Comment: For those finding this question later, this solution works because the WordPress Core processes shortcodes via a callback to the `the_content` filter. Pushing the string containing the shortcode through that filter allows the Core mechanisms to operate.